# ng-show not working on initial page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-local-storage

I am currently developping an application using Ionic - angularJS

To show the content in the home page I use the directive ng-show='isLogged', this condition has to be false to display the content.

Here is the code for the page home.html :

```
<ion-view view-title="Home" ng-app='starter'>
<ion-content class='padding' ng-show="!isLogged">
    <div class="global-speach">
    <p>You are not logged in, to continue further, please log in</p>
    <a ui-sref="logIn"><button class='button button-full button-dark'> Log In </button></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="global-speach">
    <p>Or you can create an account by clicking on the button below</p>
    <a ui-sref="signUp"><button class='button button-full button-dark'>Create an account </button></a>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

the parametter `isLogged` is defined when the user open the application

```
if (window.localStorage.getItem('isLogged') == 'true')
{
    $rootScope.isLogged = true;
    window.localStorage.setItem('isLogged', 'true');
}
else {
    $rootScope.isLogged = false;
    window.localStorage.clear();
    window.localStorage.setItem('isLogged', 'false');
}
```

My problem is that when I open the application and the variable `$rootScope.isLogged` is true the content is still displayed

I have a side menu in the application and I don't know why but when I click to open the side menu, the content disapear as expected in the begining.
For testing another part of the project I added a button in the menu bar of the application and when I click this button (used to display in console the content of localStorage) the content disapear too.

Thank you in advance for any ideas.

app.js :

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
app.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope)
{
    $ionicPlatform.ready(
    function()
    {
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard)
        {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
        if (window.localStorage.getItem('isLogged') == 'true')
        {
            $rootScope.isLogged = true;
            window.localStorage.setItem('isLogged', 'true');
        }
        else {
            $rootScope.isLogged = false;
            window.localStorage.clear();
            window.localStorage.setItem('isLogged', 'false');
        }
    });
    $rootScope.serverUrl = '';
})
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
// Home view
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
})
// Login view
$stateProvider.state('logIn', {
    url: '/logIn',
    templateUrl: 'templates/logIn.html',
    controller: 'connectionController'
})
    // Sign up view
    $stateProvider.state('signUp', {
    url: '/signUp',
    templateUrl: 'templates/signUp.html',
    controller: 'connectionController'
})
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')
});
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>Project</title>

        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

        <script src="cordova.js"></script>


        <!-- your app's js -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

        <!-- Models -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Models/sha512.js"></script>

        <!-- jquery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
        <!-- controllers -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/connectionController.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="starter">
        <ion-side-menus>
            <ion-side-menu-content>
                <ion-nav-bar class='bar-stable'>
                    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
                    <ion-nav-buttons side='left'>
                        <button class='button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon' menu-toggle='left'></button>
                    </ion-nav-buttons>
                    <ion-nav-buttons side='right'>
                        <button ng-show='isLogged' class='button' ng-controller='connectionController' ng-click='disconnect()'>Log Out</button>
                    </ion-nav-buttons>
                </ion-nav-bar>
                <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-side-menu side='left'>
                <ion-item menu-close ui-sref='home'>Home</ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close ui-sref='logIn' ng-show='!isLogged'>Log In</ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close ui-sref='signUp' ng-show='!isLogged'>Sign Up</ion-item>
           </ion-side-menu>
       </ion-side-menus>
    </body>
</html>
```

home.html :

```
<ion-view view-title="Home" ng-app='starter'>
    <ion-content class='padding' ng-show="!isLogged">
        <div class="global-speach">
            <p>You are not logged in, to continue further, please log in</p>
            <a ui-sref="logIn"><button class='button button-full button-dark'> Log In </button></a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="global-speach">
            <p>Or you can create an account by clicking on the button below</p>
            <a ui-sref="signUp"><button class='button button-full button-dark'>Create an account </button></a>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Do a `{{isLogged}}` in your view, just to check if it is really `true`.

Comment: The view don't display anything when I do `<p>{{isLogged}}</p>` but, still the same problem, when I click on the side menu, `{{isLogged}}` print `true`

Comment: Where in your app is this `$rootScope.isLogged = true;` executed?

Comment: In app.js and then the .run of the module

Comment: It seems like you don't have a controller for your view. You need to create one and set `isLogged` there. Then insert controller in the view '<ion-content class='padding' ng-show="!isLogged" ng-controller="myController">'

Comment: I tried to create a `homeController` and to set the code I use in the .run to set `$rootScope.isLogged`but the problem is still there

Comment: The only way I can help now is if I can see your code.

Comment: How could I send it to you ?

Comment: Just update the question, with the homeController and the updated view or create a plunker.

Comment: Ok I added the code

Comment: Remove `ng-app='starter'` from Home view and let me know.

Comment: Still the same probleme unfortunately

Comment: Well, if I think of something else, I will let you know.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm still looking for something too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution,

The first time I tried to create a controller for the home view I created a function to initialize the rootScope variable isLogged and call that function as the begining of home.html,

I just tried again now but without the function and it seems to be working.

here is the homeController.js:

```
app.controller('homeController', ['$rootScope',
function($rootScope){
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('isLogged') == 'true')
  {
    $rootScope.isLogged = true;
    window.localStorage.setItem('isLogged', 'true');
  }
  else {
    $rootScope.isLogged = false;
    window.localStorage.clear();
    window.localStorage.setItem('isLogged', 'false');
  }
}]);
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ng-show` then, do this instead: `ng-show="(isLogged !== 'true');"`

Comment: I tried using this condition ng-show=!isLogged without quotes but the problem still remains (when isLogged == true) the condition !IsLogged should be false so the content should not be displayed but it is

Comment: @ThomasLemaire I've changed my answer in relation to your comment, see above. Thanks.

Comment: I still have the same problem, the content is displayed until I click on the side menu. I don't understand how the side menu can affect the content

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to following code (leaving out the `''` marks around the `isLogged` variable. You want them to treat the variables as `boolean` not `strings`

```
if (window.localStorage.getItem('isLogged') == true)
{
    $rootScope.isLogged = true;
    window.localStorage.setItem('isLogged', true);
}
else {
    $rootScope.isLogged = false;
    window.localStorage.clear();
    window.localStorage.setItem('isLogged', false);
}
```

Comment: I first try with this and localStorage deal only with string so I had a problem with the condition, this is why I added the quotes. I don't think the problem come from this block because I have the correct value of isLogged in the $rootscope